# Achieving high DNS QPS throughput

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, azure, bind, udp

I'm trying to find the maximum QPS (Query Per Second) of the DNS Resolver VM.

We have our infrastructure hosted on Azure, having a VM (bind based) acting as a resolver querying Azure native DNS (`168.63.129.16`) as well as on-prem DNS. I'm not caching any query on the resolver & each A-record has a TTL of 300 seconds.

I'm using `dnsperf` & `resperf` to trigger the load (only A-records). Now, that I'm preparing DNS resolvers to withstand DDOS attacks of up to 100K QPS. I'm facing issues like query ratelimiting between my resolver & azure native DNS resolver. As a result of this, when QPS is increased, the resolver returns `SERVFAIL` responses back to the client. However, we didn't see any `SERVFAIL` responses between resolver & on-prem-based DNS.

Maximum QPS, I could see while targeting Azure DNS is around 2100. I've searched a lot online if there is any such rate-limiting done by Azure, but couldn't find anything related. Somehow, I hunch resolver VM hit bottleneck as 2K QPS is very low for the scale of Azure infrastructure.

A few things (kernel sysctl changes), I changed at my end which improved a bit but not much.

> Bind Config changes ::

- `recursive-clients` from `1000` -> `30000`

> UDP buffers to a higher value than `26214400` to stop buffer failures::

- `net.core.rmem_max`
- `net.core.rmem_default`

> Local port range from `32768 61000` to `1024 61000` to have maximum
> ports available for DNS::

- `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range`

> miscellaneous changes::

- `txqueuelen` from `1000` -> `20000`
- `ulimits` changed to 100000
- `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max` changed to a much higher value

In addition to the above, I did increase the VM size from (1 core, 2 GB RAM) -> (4 core, 8 GB RAM). After increasing, packet errors disappeared (checked `netstat -s`) but didn't improve `SERVFAIL` errors.

I did enable `tcpdump` to check the pattern of `SERVFAIL` errors. In case of failures, the resolver tries to send the query to Azure DNS 5 times (each after 1 sec), but it hasn't heard anything from Azure DNS & hence sending the `SERVFAIL` response back to the client. Having loaded the `pcap` file onto `Wireshark`, I see Azure DNS sends the response back to `resolver` but `resolver` had already sent the `SERVFAIL` response to the client.

Why is the connection closed before having the response? Current `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout` is left untouched to `30` seconds but `resolver` sends `SERVFAIL` after 5 seconds to client.

Below are `tcpdump` logs during `ServFail`::

```
reading from file dns4.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
10.0.0.10.57710 > 10.0.0.11.domain: [udp sum ok] 1612+ A? SZxvvdyDYy.ns.westeurope.xx.yy.zz.net. (66)
10.0.0.11.44513 > 168.63.129.16.domain: [bad udp cksum 0xbecd -> 0x8cfd!] 52637+% [1au] A? SZxvvdyDYy.ns.westeurope.xx.yy.zz.net. ar: . OPT UDPsize=4096 DO (77)
10.0.0.11.32378 > 168.63.129.16.domain: [bad udp cksum 0xbecd -> 0x3950!] 20672+% [1au] A? SZxvvdyDYy.ns.westeurope.xx.yy.zz.net. ar: . OPT UDPsize=512 DO (77)
10.0.0.11.59973 > 168.63.129.16.domain: [bad udp cksum 0xbecd -> 0xe2e5!] 15199+% [1au] A? SZxvvdyDYy.ns.westeurope.xx.yy.zz.net. ar: . OPT UDPsize=512 DO (77)
10.0.0.11.29976 > 168.63.129.16.domain: [bad udp cksum 0xbec2 -> 0x051b!] 47104+ A? SZxvvdyDYy.ns.westeurope.xx.yy.zz.net. (66)
10.0.0.11.43442 > 168.63.129.16.domain: [bad udp cksum 0xbec2 -> 0xe791!] 41199+ A? SZxvvdyDYy.ns.westeurope.xx.yy.zz.net. (66)
10.0.0.11.domain > 10.0.0.10.57710: [bad udp cksum 0x2a89 -> 0x5e30!] 1612 ServFail q: A? SZxvvdyDYy.ns.westeurope.xx.yy.zz.net. 0/0/0 (66)
```

As you can see from the bottom line `ServFail` is sent after 5 attempts.

If you have come this far, I must thank you for reading this lengthy question. I know this is too much of an ask, but I appreciate it if you have some hints for me as I'm unable to get what's the bottleneck.

Originally posted on superuser [here](https://superuser.com/posts/1714289/edit)

Comment: "bad udp cksum" might be something you want to investigate. Could be a sign of faulty equipment/network connection somewhere, or bugs in kernel/network card driver (less probable). Also the recursive nameserver you are using can rate limit you. Not really sure to understand if you are setting up an authoritative nameserver why you depend on a recursive one, and if you setup a recursive one why it doesn't have cache and depend on another one too.

Comment: Hi @PatrickMevzek, thanks for your reply. I'm suspecting the same with rate limiting from azure authoritative server `168.63.129.16`. Despite repeated tests, QPS isn't going beyond `2100`. I'm not setting up `authoritative ns`, it's just `recursive ns`, relying on `azure` for azure records, on-prem for on-prem records. No caching at recursive ns level...

Comment: Regarding `bad udp cksum`, I've this on almost every query. I would need to investigate why it's so rampant.. Mostly, I don't think it's the root cause of this `ServFail`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'll answer my question.

Indeed Azure rate limits Queries per Second to `1000` per VM.

It's documented [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-faq#what-are-the-usage-limits-for-azure-dns-). No matter whatever `sysctl` tuning I do, we still have issues from Azure because of this rate limiting.